# Apply function doesnt work, the type error is TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python

I don´t Know why it doesnt work, I want to use the function in a dataframe using apply, but the type error is TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

```
df[column1]  = ['https://www.some_text.com/ar?cc+cc&q={keyword}',
'https://www.some_text.com/ar?fsd+fsd&q={keyword}',
'https://www.some_text.com/ar?xc+sdc&q={keyword}']
url_s = 'some_text'
url_f = 'some_text_2'

def url_name(x):
        if url_s in x:
        a = x.replace(url_s,url_f)
        return a

df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(url_name)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please update to include a [mcve] including a sample of `df['column1']`. The error states that the variable you're trying to `apply` to is `None`

Answer (score 0):

There was a minor problem with your indentation in the IF loop which could have caused the error. Everything else seemed to work.

```
url_s = 'some_text'
url_f = 'some_text_2'

def url_name(x):

        if url_s in x:
            a = x.replace(url_s,url_f)
        return a    


d = {'column1': ['https://www.some_text.com/ar?cc+cc&q={keyword}',
'https://www.some_text.com/ar?fsd+fsd&q={keyword}',
'https://www.some_text.com/ar?xc+sdc&q={keyword}']}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(url_name)
```

And this is the result.

```
df
Out[22]: 
                                             column1
0   https://www.some_text_2.com/ar?cc+cc&q={keyword}
1  https://www.some_text_2.com/ar?fsd+fsd&q={keyw...
2  https://www.some_text_2.com/ar?xc+sdc&q={keyword}
```

Hope this helps!